# asp.net local database search and adding data

Tags: asp.net

I have a problem with searching in my database in asp.net MVC5 app. I added to my index:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>Wyszukaj</div>
    <div>@Html.TextBox("Search")</div>
    <input type="submit" value="search" />
}
```

And to my controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string search)
    {
        var searching = from m in db.Books
                     select m;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
        {
            searching = searching.Where(s => s.Tytul.Contains(search));
        }

        return View(db.Books);
    }
```

But if I type text in window and click searching, I can't see results, it is still list of my books.

I'm also unable to see the data I saved to database before running my app. When I'm trying to see my table data it's still there, but after running app, I can't see the data. 
When app is running I can add the data and the data is visible in every run, but not in my table data. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What  kind of EntityFramework are you using? CodeFirst or Database First?

Comment: I'm using Entity Framework 6.1.3, Database First

Comment: You can do several things for find solution. first add breakpoint and look at  what happens in action. Losing data after running app only happens when you use code first and write dropcreatdatabaseAlways.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in action after adding breakpoint. But maybe.. may it happen, because I didn't add any connection string? I thought if it is only local database, it won't be needed.